# csv to SQLite how to eliminate the empty cells on CSV or how to eliminate null on SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, csv, xlsx

I encountered some questions when I was trying to upload a CSV file to SQLite using Python 3.

I originally had a file in XLSX format, which I then converted to CSV. My file looks like this:

A   B   C

Ava David   Amber

```
Gabby   

Eric
```

Then I uploaded the file to SQLite and encountered a lot of NULL values. like this:

A   B   C

Ava David   Amber

null    Gabby   null

null    Eric    null

I wanted to leave them empty without displaying 'null', but I don't know how to make it happen. Should I do something on the original excel or the CSV? Or just

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename')
connection = sqlite3.connect('SQLitename.db')
df.to_sql('tablename', connection, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: Is it just a display issue? I doubt the string null was put in your db